# Creating a MySQL Database : root issues

Tags: php, mysql

I'm on a Laravel 5.8 Tutorial to Build a First CRUD App with Laravel and MySQL (PHP 7.1+).
On the part to create a MySql database, I have to run that following command line :

```
mysql -u root -p
```

on the terminal.

But I have this following answer :

> PS C:\Users\Anne-So\Documents\Web_développement\Projet_Sesame\laravel\laravel-first-crud-app> mysql -u root -p
>   mysql : Le terme «mysql» n'est pas reconnu comme nom d'applet de commande, fonction, fichier de script ou programme exécutable. Vérifiez l'orthographe du nom, ou si 
>   un chemin d'accès existe, vérifiez que le chemin d'accès est correct et réessayez.
>   Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
>   + mysql -u root -p
>   + ~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (mysql:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
>   ""

how can I fix it?

Comment: It would appear that you do not have MySQL installed or running.

Comment: It means that an executable called "mysql" could not be found. Check whether the MySQL installation folder is in your PATH environment variable. (It's possible the tutorial is expecting you to run on Mac or Linux where that kind of thing is usually less of an issue than in Windows). Also...try running it from a normal Command Prompt instead of a Powershell session.

Comment: thank you i get  an idea of the problem.